# How to use Bangladesh Currency into Font-Awesome icon

Tags: html

Could someone please tell me what unicode and or HTML-escape code the bangladesh currency(৳) has?

Comment: So what exactly is your question? Are you asking how you convert the currency symbol into an icon?

Comment: and according to this [thread](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/1719) there is no such icon

Comment: So what exactly is your question? Are you asking how you convert the currency symbol into an icon? yes. i wanted to asking what is html or Unicode or Hex code of Bangladesh currency symbol.

Comment: If an answer statisfies you question, please mark it as `accepted` with the checkmark on the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This sign is currently unavailable in font awesome. However, you can use any of these codes below to get the symbol in your code. I know it's not a perfect answer, but I hope it helps!

BENGALI RUPEE SIGN ৳

UNICODE:
`U+009F3`

HEX CODE:
`&#x09F3;`

HTML CODE:
 `&#2547;`

(source: https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/currency/)

Comment: UNICODE: U+009F3

HEX CODE: &#x09F3;

HTML CODE: &#2547; I am use it then solve to use Bangladesh currency symbol.thanks

Comment: I found the information on [this](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+09F3) link.